# List as python dict element (adding and updating)

Tags: python, dictionary

I get totally confused with this task. Here's the problem: I need to check all ip belongs to certain domains and then put into a dict a domains with shared one IP. So here's the code I wrote:

```
def check_ip(domain):     
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
    return ip

def worker_function(input_queue, output_queue):
    global list_unvalid, list_valid, ips_domains 

    while True:
        try:
            data = input_queue.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            break
        parts = re.findall('http(s)*://(.+?)/(.+)$', data)
        domain = parts[0][1]
        print("checking " + domain)
        try:
            ip = check_ip(domain)             
            with mylock:           
                ips_domains[ip].append(domain)                  
            #output_queue.put_nowait(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception ' + str(e))

        input_queue.task_done()
```

But instead I've got an exception "Exception 'ip here'" every time. I think something wrong with the syntax, that appends values to the dict. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: how is your `ips_domains` defined?

Comment: @FlyingTeller ips_domains = dict()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is in

```
ips_domains[ip].append(domain)
```

Since `ips_domains` is an empty dictionary, `ips_domains[ip]` is not a list object and you cannot call `.append()` on it. If you havn't seen the ip before you need to initialize the dict entry as an empty list:

```
if not ip in ips_domains:
    ips_domains[ip]=[]
ips_domains[ip].append(domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you try to add a domain to an ip, there isn't a list in there to which you can add the domain. For every ip, you must first initialize an empty list.

If you change your dict to `ips_domains = defaultdict(list)`, an empty list is added to the dictionary the first time you try add a domain to an ip.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

eg:

```
>>> a=dict()
>>> a["key"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'key'
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> b=defaultdict(list)
>>> b["key"]
[]
>>> b
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'key': []})
>>>
```